# A video player based on QtAV with Direct2D / OpenGL rendering

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, ffmpeg, direct2d

I'm developing a video player in Qt C++ using QtAV. QtAV uses ffmpeg internally. I need to show semi transparent overlays both my watermark logo and subtitles. I'm writing the application for windows. I use OpenAL library. OpenGL and Direct2D are the choice for renderers.

If I use OpenGL renderer, it works fine in some systems. The overlay works fine. But in some other systems the whole application will be just a black window. Nothing else I can see.

If I use Direct2D, the overlay wont work. And the renderer is a bit slow. But it works on all systems, without this overlays.

I have no code to show here because its not the coding issue. Even the examples in QtAV are not working. I need to find a way to show the overlays using Direct2D renderer OR find a solid way to use OpenGL rendering on all systems without fail.

Comment: I know how to write your player using ffmpeg and there are lots of example on internet which u can use. but if you choose a library like QtAV you should contact them about anything seems wrong. the library is not common and maybe not in a good state right now in some parts! so add the QtAV tag to your question and plz contact them using github or at least an email. Good luck. It seems QtAV is an active library which is great and hopefully they can resolve your problem easily, if it's a simple one.

Comment: It seems that the systems you mention doesn't provide proper support for OGL. Is there some relation between the video cards on those systems? You may try updating the video drivers to latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Direct2D is not well supported in QtAV. So you may need to implement your own functions to add filters in your video render. That includes text draw functions, setting transparency etc.